# Identify which range the number lies between two columns in a table

Tags: oracle

I need a query and i have the table like below

```
Key StartNum EndNum
--- -------- ------
A   1        3
B   6        8
C   10       15
```

if i give the value like 2 then my resultset should display like below

```
Key StartNum EndNum
--- -------- ------
A   1        3
```

if the value is 12 then

```
Key StartNum EndNum
--- -------- ------
A   10        15
```

Comment: The question doesn't appear to include any attempt at all to solve the problem. Please edit the question to show what you've tried, and show a specific roadblock you're running into with [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). For more information, please see [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
SELECT *
FROM yourTable
WHERE ? BETWEEN StartNum AND EndNum;
```

Replace the `?` placeholder with the value you want to search (or bind this value to `?`, if you are using a prepared statement).

Answer (score 1):

Below query should give expected result

```
select key,StartNum ,EndNum from TABLE
where StartNum < :value and EndNum >:value;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this

```
with mytab(key,startnum,endnum) as 
(select 'A',1,3 from dual
union all
select 'B',6,8 from dual
union all
select 'C',10,15 from dual)
select * from mytab where &input between startnum and endnum
```